# Getting Max Salary For Each Employee

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I am trying to get the max salary for each employee.

```
select e.first_name, e.last_name, t.title, s.salary
from employees e inner join titles t on e.emp_no = t.emp_no
inner join salaries s on e.emp_no = s.emp_no
where s.salary in (select max(salary) from salaries group by emp_no);
```

But I keep getting all salaries for each employee and not the max.  What am I missing here?

BTW I am using the sample employee DB from here.
https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reference from `outer query` to make it `correlated` subquery :

```
select e.first_name, e.last_name, t.title, s.salary
from employees e inner join 
     titles t 
     on e.emp_no = t.emp_no inner join 
     salaries s 
     on e.emp_no = s.emp_no
where s.salary = (select max(s1.salary) from salaries s1 where s1.emp_no = e.emp_no);
```

Answer (score 2):

`group by` is very handy for this situation

```
select 
  e.first_name, 
  e.last_name, 
  t.title,  
  max(s.salary)
from employees e 
inner join titles t 
  on e.emp_no = t.emp_no
inner join salaries s 
  on e.emp_no = s.emp_no
group by 
  e.first_namme, 
  e.last_name, 
  t.title
```